# WebClient find outgoing IP address

Tags: webclient

My .Net website uses `WebClient` to download a resource from another server.  I am receiving "403 forbidden" responses from the remote server.

I think there is some sort of firewall issue as the requests work from my home development environment but the same requests are refused when my site is deployed to a web hosting company. I want to find the IP address that the refused requests originate from.

**My question is this**: is there a way to programatically find the actual source IP Address used by WebClient when it made the request?

I know the public IP address of my website but this might not be the same address WebClient would use for outgoing traffic.  Unfortunately I have very limited access to the hosting company shared server and can't see any IIS logs or any other logs of incoming or outgoing traffic.  Hence I am trying to get this IP address programatically.

I have seen SO questions on how to request a specific outgoing IP using `BindIPEndPointCallback`, but none on how to discover an actual actual IP used.

Comment: I think you can try to the Remote address using using operating system command .Can use tools like wireshark or  TCP view

Comment: thanks Pushpendra, running on a shared server I doubt that I would have been able to install or run any tools that allowed me to spy on network traffic for security reasons

Comment: Thanks to everyone who had a look at this.  The firewall problem that prompted this question is now resolved and the issue is no longer relevant.